# I can't add a validation to react-select component

Tags: reactjs

This is my code:

```
    <Select
        inputValue={inputValue}
        isClearable={false}
        isMulti
        name="domains"
        getOptionLabel={domain => domain.name}
        getOptionValue={domain => domain.id}
        options={domains}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange}
        onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
        value={selectedDomains}
        className="basic-multi-select"
        classNamePrefix="select"
        required
    />
</div>
<FormFeedback>
    {errors.selectedDomains && errors.selectedDomains.message}
</FormFeedback>
```

And this is my function:

```
isValidForm = () => {
    if (selectedDomains === null) {
        errors.selectedDomains = {
            message: "Please select domain"
        };
    }
    if (Object.entries(errors).length !== 0) {
        return this.setState({ errors }, () => false);
    }
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Where are you calling `isValidForm()`

Comment: Before the render

Comment: Need more code to be able to help

Comment: which code do you need @KieranQuinn?!

Comment: Hi @BrahimKRAIEM, could you provide the code for the component? Or a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with a working example?

Comment: @AxelJunes this is my file in sandbox: i would like to add validation to activity domain Select in the file editUser.js https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-dhawan-1r79z